# How to access Parse.com Relation Data

Tags: android, parse-platform, relation

I need data from user to question . I've and access separately data (_User and Question data) but i need relation access.For ex i need access question title from _User class.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This might work. The following will take the questions from the current logged user.

```
ParseUser user = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
ParseRelation<ParseObject> relation = user.getRelation("question_id");
relation.getQuery().findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
    void done(List<ParseObject> results, ParseException e) {
      if (e != null) {
        // There was an error
      } else {
        // results have all the questions
      }
    }
});
```